# Upload recorded video directly from my android app to my youtube channel

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am making an android app which required recording video and uploading it to Youtube.

Now I am able to record the video but I am unable to figure out how to upload it to Youtube . Also all users will upload the video but it should be uploaded to my channel on Youtube . I searched on S.O. but I am getting obsolete results which are not useful now.

I tried using Youtube data v3 api but there is no sample code for video upload on the website to use it in Android. I tried to use the java code ([this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)) but there are imports like AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp and LocalServerReceiver which are not imported and when I searched for it on internet, I found people saying that we should not import it in android.

These imports are required:
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
Am I doing something wrong here or missing something really important?

** Please explain how to implement the functionality of uploading video to Youtube from my android app. thanks **

Comment: Yes, my application is registered

Comment: I even tried their sample code after going through their documentation. I wrote where I got stuck as well.

Comment: This one: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Comment: The link you sent, they are showing MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener. And the link I posted, they are also using MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener to upload. But I got stuck when running their sample. I wrote that in my question as well. If you know any workaround for that?

Comment: I just want to implement this functionality. I don't have any issue with any imports. In the link you sent, we need to Authorise video upload. Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "uploadvideo");                                                                             It is not able to detect Auth because its from samples. So I changed it to import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential; But it won't work. Any clue?